# change date format in sql database

Tags: php, mysql, date

In sql datbase when date datatype is used it stores date in **yyyy-mm-dd** format
is there any way to change it to **dd-mm-yyyy**? as i want to display date in dd-mm-yyyy format. One way or another would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can either change the column type to VARCHAR(10) and format it to your liking on insertion or preferably you can format it with php after retrieval like:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's built in DATE_FORMAT function in the query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

OR

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datefield, GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR'));
```

If you use `GET_FORMAT(DATE,'EUR')` it will use `.` instead of `-` as the separator though.

Comment: This is probably the best solution... though to say for sure would depend on workflow and preference.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to save your date in UNIX format so you can use

```
date("<IDENTIFER>", $timestampUNIX);
```

to make a timestamp in any format you want. For identifers use
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

For this you have to change your database-colum-type to INT.

Comment: Though this is perfectly acceptable it does make it hard for a human to make heads or tails of the data without converting it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that there is no problem if it will be stored in yyyy-mm-dd format, but during output you     can use date function - >

```
date("d-m-Y", strtotime($datefrombase));
```